# 18.04 Freezes upon network use with iwlwifi errors in kernel.log

Tags: 18.04, kernel, iwlwifi

Recently, my Ubuntu 18.04 installation began having the following issues whenever I accessed a significant quantity of data over wifi (e.g. running speedtest):

- Freezing for ~20 seconds
- iwlwifi errors in `/var/log/kernel.log`
- This error: `[drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=9024 end=9025) time 3029 us, min 1073, max 1079, scanline start 989, end 71`

This did not start immediately after any kernel updates or updates to anything that looks to me to be related to iwlwifi (although I will be happy to check `apt.log` if there are any specific packages I should be looking out for.

The output in `/var/log/kernel.log` during the duration of the freeze can be found in this [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/bc1ZTMuQ).

Network controller information:

```
→ ~ $ lspci -kvnn | sed -n '/Network/,/^$/ p'
3d:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 [8086:2526] (rev 29)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device [1a56:1550]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at ed200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Wireless and everything else is working perfectly normally on Windows on the same computer.

Could anyone provide me with a direction in how I should go about troubleshooting this? Thank you.

**Update**: The same issues occurred on a fresh install of Ubuntu MATE 18.04 on the same machine.

**Update 2**: These errors do not occur as far as I can tell so far with the earlier kernel version I have installed (5.0.0-23 as compared to 5.3.0-28).